# ASP.Net Authentication with OAuth and ADFS depending on path

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, adfs

We have an existing ASP.Net site that needs authentication. I've implemented the  code below.

The application needs authentication on the following paths:

```
/admin     - ADFS
/edx/links - ADFS
/api       - OAuth
```

The Api is used by an App and should be authenticated with OAuth and not ADFS but the app gets redirected to the ADFS server nontheless.

Can we do what's described in 1 site or do we have to split the site in two (1 for web access and the api)? I would prefer the 1 site option.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOwinExceptionLogger();
        app.SetLoggerFactory(new OwinLoggerFactory());

        var config = new HttpConfiguration { DependencyResolver = new StructureMapResolver(Container) };
        var settings = Container.GetInstance<ISettings>();

        ConfigureOAuth(app, settings);
        app.Map("/admin", inner => ConfigureAuth(inner, settings));
        app.Map("/edx/links", inner => ConfigureAuth(inner, settings));

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    private static void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, ISettings settings)
    {
        var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider(),
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);

        app.Use(async (context, next) => { await next.Invoke(); });
    }

    private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app, ISettings settings)
    {
        // Work-around to fix Katana issue 197: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/197
        // https://github.com/KentorIT/owin-cookie-saver
        // app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
        });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = settings.WsFedRealm,
                MetadataAddress = settings.WsFedMetadataUrl,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = ClaimsExtensions.WurNameIdentifier,
                    SaveSigninToken = true
                },
                Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    MessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Info($"Message received {context.ProtocolMessage}");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Info($"Redirect to identity provider {context?.Request?.Uri?.AbsolutePath}");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Info("Security token validated");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    SecurityTokenReceived = context =>
                    {
                        Log.Info($"SecurityTokenReceived {context?.Response?.ReasonPhrase}");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("~/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });

        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Name;
    }
```

Comment: Nobody has a clue

Comment: ADFS supports OAuth. So, I'm confused as to why you would consider this differently.